# How to check if second argument is empty in discord.js v12

Tags: discord.js, args

My project is a reputation bot. There is a embed that displays the stars and a comment. I wanna check if the second arg(args[1]) is empty and if it is return.
Here is a hastebin with my code: https://hastebin.com/kuvufejoqa.js
I tried using `if(!comment.length) return;` and it didn't work.
Here is what I don't want in the embed:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if 2nd argument is empty use

```
if(!args[1]) return;
```

args[1] is 2nd argument and if you add ! before it, it will check if it's empty

Comment: I think I did that before, but didn't place it on the right location. It worked. Thank you!

Comment: No problem! I'm glad I helped you!